# How to prevent Quantity calculations from converting units

Tags: units, upvalues

I have an accrual calculation that I would like to preserve the units even though they are of the same dimension (e.g. time). For example, I would like the following

```
Quantity[5, "Days"] / Quantity[52, "Weeks"]
```

to return in units of *`days per week`* instead of a unitless number. Later in the process I would like to multiply the result by some number of weeks (`Quantity[_, "Week"]`) and have the result in day units.

I know about `IndependentUnit` but prefer that the units in the result still be known to Mathematica (`KnownUnitQ` true) for other purposes.

I have tried this with `UpValues` (my first `UpValues` attempt) with the following but I get an error.

```
Quantity /: 
 op : (Alternatives @@ (Symbol /@ 
       WolframLanguageData[
        EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", 
          {"FunctionalityArea", "MathOperationFunctions"}], "Name"]))[
   Quantity[v1_, u1_],
   Quantity[v2_, u2_]
   ] :=
 Quantity[op[v1, v2], op[u1, u2]]
```

Is it possible to do this or force a unit hold in quantity calculations?

I am expecting

```
Quantity[5, "Days"] / Quantity[52, "Weeks"]
```

to give the result that the following gives

```
Quantity[5/52, "Days"/"Weeks"]

(* Quantity[5/52, ("Days")/("Weeks")] *)
```

[image]

Comment: `IndependentUnit` are actually `KnownUnitQ`. Wouldn't that be enough for your purpose?

Comment: @Xavier I should have put `CompatibleUnitQ` not `KnownUnitQ`.  Else I will not be able to use it with other conversions later on.

Answer (score 3):

Products of quantities are handled by (see `PrintDefinitions[Quantity]`)

```
Quantity /: 
HoldPattern[Times][Longest[e2___], q_?QuantityQ, Shortest[e1, ___] /; 
    QuantityUnits`$AutomaticUnitTimes === True := ...
```

which calls `` QuantityUnits`Private`qTimes `` and in turn `` QuantityUnits`Private`iqTimes ``. A way to go is to redefine this last function only

```
(* Ensures the symbol exists from a fresh kernel for unprotecting it *)
System`Quantity;

Unprotect[Quantity];

QuantityUnits`Private`iqTimes[QuantityUnits`Private`q_List] := Module[{units},

        With[{vlist = QuantityUnits`Private`q[[All, 1]], 
              ulist = QuantityUnits`Private`q[[All, 2]]},

             units = Apply[Times, ulist];
             Quantity[Apply[Times, vlist], units]
        ]
];

Protect[Quantity];
```

This yields the desired outputs

```
Quantity[5, "Days"] / Quantity[52, "Weeks"]

(* Quantity[5/52, ("Days")/("Weeks")] *)
```

[image]

```
Quantity[2, "Weeks"] * %

(* Quantity[5/26, "Days"] *)
```

[image]

Your code and the above redefinition could also be enclosed in a `Block`. Note that even though the modifications seem minimum, there is the possibility that this redefinition breaks other things as it can happen when redefining built-in symbols.

Comment: This is a scary solution but it works (+1).  I am not too keen on `Unprotect` as there are many warnings about unintended consequences.  You also provide those warnings.

Comment: Since posting the question I developed an *almost* working solution that is less scary that I will post as an answer. I would appreciate if you would have a look to see if you can fix my outstanding issue with my *almost* solution.

Comment: Per scary solution - I agree. This approach was in the line of your proposition with `UpValues`, which would have required unprotecting `Quantity` to make it work. Here, it is *slightly* less dangerous ;).

Comment: Per your post - Ok, I'll have a look at it.

Comment: Actually you don't need the `Unprotect` at all as you are only making definitions for `iqTimes` and that is not protected. Of course that doesn't change the fact that you are changing system behavior and that is dangerous, no matter whether the symbol you are manipulating happens to be public and protected or private and not protected ...

Comment: @AlbertRetey Yes good point, I overlooked that; `Unprotect` can be removed.

Answer (score 2):

Since it's a financial calculation I would think you would want something with a minimum chance of behaving unexpectedly.  Hence I offer this very simple approach, which should be completely canonical. It gives an output form close to what you requested:

```
a = HoldForm[Quantity[5, "Days"]/Quantity[52, "Weeks"]]
```

> > $\dfrac{5 \text{ days}}{52\text{ wk}}$

```
UnitConvert[ReleaseHold@a*Quantity[26., "Weeks"], "Days"]
```

> > 2.5 days

Or you may prefer this syntax, which works as well:

```
UnitConvert[a*Quantity[26., "Weeks"], "Days"]//ReleaseHold
```

And if you don't want to specify HoldForm each time:

```
f[days_, weeks_] := HoldForm[Quantity[days, "Days"]/Quantity[weeks, "Weeks"]] 
f[5, 52]
```

> > $\dfrac{5 \text{ days}}{52\text{ wk}}$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain if I should post this as an answer or an edit to the OP. It seems it is more of an answer so I put it here.

Since posting this question have and developed and answer that *amost* works. It is pattern matching based and works for the `"MathOperationFunctions"` except for `Divide`.

```
qtyUnitHoldRule=
   (op:Alternatives @@ (Symbol /@ 
       WolframLanguageData[
          EntityClass["WolframLanguageSymbol", 
              {"FunctionalityArea", "MathOperationFunctions"}], "Name"])
     )[q1_?QuantityQ, q2_?QuantityQ ] -> 
          Quantity[op @@ QuantityMagnitude[{q1, q2}], op @@ QuantityUnit[{q1, q2}]]
```

`qtyUnitHoldRule` will be used to convert move the `Quantity` arithmetic between two quantities inside of one `Quantity` object.

```
Remove[holdQuantityUnits];
Attributes[holdQuantityUnits]={HoldAllComplete};
holdQuantityUnits[code_] := Unevaluated[code] //. qtyUnitHoldRule
```

`Quantity` arithmetic will be wrapped in `holdQuantityUnits` so that `qtyUnitHoldRule` can be `ReplaceRepeated` to convert all instances of this arithmetic.

This works for the `"MathOperationFunctions"` functions I have tested but does not work for the notation form of `Divide` (i.e. `/`).

```
holdQuantityUnits[
    x=Quantity[5,"Days"];
    y=Quantity[52,"Weeks"];
    {Divide[x,y], x / y}
]

(* {Quantity[5/52, ("Days")/("Weeks")], 5 / 364} *)
```

Any ideas how I can extend this to include the notation form of `Divide`?

Comment: From a fresh kernel on both 10.3 and 10.4, the first evaluation of `holdQuantityUnits` gives me `{5/364, 5/364}`, and the second evaluation returns `{Quantity[5/52, ("Days")/("Weeks")], Quantity[5/52, ("Days")/("Weeks")]}`. I do not have the difference you mention.

Comment: @Xavier Maybe I need a fresh kernel. However, my installed Mathematica has crashed and I am having licensing issues so only have Mathematica Online and it does not appear to like the definition of `qtyUnitHoldRule` so I may have to wait until I get home to continue.

Comment: Perhaps this additional rule could make it work: `Times[Power[q1_?QuantityQ, p1_.], Power[q2_?QuantityQ, p2_?Negative]] :> Quantity[Divide @@ QuantityMagnitude[{q1, q2}], Divide @@ QuantityUnit[{q1^p1, q2^(-p2)}]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another simple, semi-aggressive way to do this. First we'll note that we have these:

```
Names["QuantityUnits`$Automatic*"]

{"QuantityUnits`$AutomaticUnitParsing", \
"QuantityUnits`$AutomaticUnitPlus", \
"QuantityUnits`$AutomaticUnitTimes"}
```

And so we'll just `Block` all of them.

```
withHeldUnits[expr_] :=
  Block[{QuantityUnits`$AutomaticUnitParsing,
    QuantityUnits`$AutomaticUnitPlus,
    QuantityUnits`$AutomaticUnitTimes},
   expr
   ];
withHeldUnits~SetAttributes~HoldFirst

(Quantity["SpeedOfLight"] + Quantity[2, "Angstroms"/"Seconds"])
withHeldUnits@(Quantity["SpeedOfLight"] + 
   Quantity[2, "Angstroms"/"Seconds"])

Quantity[2997924580000000002, ("Angstroms")/("Seconds")]

Quantity[2, ("Angstroms")/("Seconds")] + Quantity[1, "SpeedOfLight"]
```